# Parallax Corrected Cubemaps in Opengl?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I have been trying to imploment parallax corrected local cubemaps in OpenGL for a little while now, but I've not really managed to get anywhere, does anybody know where to start?

Here is my current shader code:

Fragment:

```
#version 330
in vec2 TexCoord;
in vec3 Normal; 
in vec3 Position; 
in vec3 Color;
out vec4 color; 

uniform samplerCube CubeMap; 
uniform vec3 CameraPosition; 



void main() {
    vec4 OutColor = vec4(Color,1.0); 

    vec3 normal = normalize(Normal); 
    vec3 view = normalize(Position-CameraPosition); 
    vec3 ReflectionVector = reflect(view,normal); 
    vec4 ReflectionColor = texture(CubeMap,ReflectionVector); 

    OutColor = mix(OutColor,ReflectionColor,0.5); 
    color = OutColor; 

}
```

Vertex:

```
#version 330

layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout (location = 2) in vec3 normal;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 texCoord;
layout (location = 3) in vec3 color;

out vec2 TexCoord;
out vec3 Normal; 
out vec3 Position; 
out vec3 Color; 
uniform mat4 ModelMatrix;
uniform mat4 ViewMatrix;
uniform mat4 ProjectionMatrix;
void main()
{
    gl_Position = ProjectionMatrix * ViewMatrix * ModelMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0f);
    TexCoord=texCoord;
    Normal = normal;  
    Position = vec4(ModelMatrix * vec4(position,1.0)).xyz;  
    Color = color;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> Position = vec4(ModelMatrix * vec4(position,1.0)).xyz;
> ```

This puts the `Position` output variable into world space. Assuming the `CameraPosition` uniform is also in world space, then:

> ```
> vec3 view = normalize(Position-CameraPosition);
> ```

`view` will also be in world space.

However, `Normal` comes directly from the vertex attribute. So unless you are updating each vertex's `Normal` value every time you rotate the object, that value will probably be in model space. And therefore:

> ```
> vec3 ReflectionVector = reflect(view,normal);
> ```

This statement is *incoherent*. `view` is in one space, while `normal` is in another. And you can't really perform reasonable operations on vectors that are in different coordinate systems.

You need to make sure that `Normal`, `Position`, and `CameraPosition` are all in the same space. If you want that space to be world space, then you need to transform `Normal` into world space. Which in the general case requires computing the inverse/transpose of your model-to-world matrix.